# Insert formula with reference to active cell row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a formula into a cell and trying to use a dynamic cell reference by using ActiveCell.Row.

```
Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(Range(""P"" & ActiveCell.Row).Address ="""",""DD/MM/YYY"",CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS(O21,P21),"" Working Days""))"
```

But I am getting an application defined error.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(" & Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Address & " ="""",""DD/MM/YYY"",CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS(O21,P21),"" Working Days""))"
```

You have to comment out the VBA code in the string.

Comment: thanks this did the trick! will accept the answer in a few minutes. cheers